# Oracle Autonomous database JDBC Error No more data to read from socket but webapp works without errors

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Trying to setup a db connection pool with dbcp2 and Oracle db in cloud.

Encountering this error when attempting to connect to Oracle Autonomous database. Weirdest part is even though this error is encountered I dont get any errors when interacting with services built on the webapp when this connection pool begins to get used for ex adding a user, extracting reports etc.

The database is tcps enabled and I am using Oracle Wallets to connect to the same.

Error is consistently reproduced, so on the fence if its some network issue

Any ideas what might be causing this error?

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error preloading the connection pool
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:573) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:734) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at com.testme.mmappserver.upgrade.start.MartUpgrade.isMartVersionPresent(MartUpgrade.java:176) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.testme.mmappserver.upgrade.start.MartUpgrade.upgrade(MartUpgrade.java:129) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.testme.mmappserver.upgrade.start.MartUpgrade.upgrade_main(MartUpgrade.java:81) [classes/:?]
    at com.testme.mmappserver.upgrade.Configui$11.run(Configui.java:499) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:784) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:429) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIpro.receive(T4C8TTIpro.java:134) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1623) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:52) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:357) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:918) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1023) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:569) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.8.0.jar:2.8.0]
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: So do you see this error just occasionally during the day, or just at startup, or every time a user logs in?

Comment: @MarkStewart I get the error when attempting to execute a procedure during the startup

Comment: In theory, the `java.sql.SQLRecoverableException` is used when a particular statement could potentially work, if invoked again, after issues such as a tablespace was out of space (and later fixed), a timeout occurred, etc.   Now, it would be nice if you can find out what is causing the _first_ try to fail, but you may want to try (temporarily) to put that statement in a loop, with a pause in the loop for say 60 seconds, and loop for maybe 5 times.  Then if it works on the second time, always... that could be a work-around.

Comment: the error was not being reproduced in any another dev machine so probably something wrong wih my env. ignoring it for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the Oracle JDBC driver you're using is very old. I would recommend you to update that to the latest appropriate one for your DBMS version.
Please refer the attached page url, this might be helpful.

[Error:No more data to read from socket](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2347945/oracle-sqlexception-no-more-data-to-read-from-socket)

Comment: I am already using the driver applicable for my database. ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're exceeding the total number of connections that are allowed to your autonomous database. So you may just add a limit to your dbcp2 pool. You can try with just a couple of connections (for init, min and max) and see if the error reproduces.